# Why is 'admin' missing from my admin links?

Tags: php, localhost

I cloned a wordpress site to my local machine. 
Then I ran PHP's built in web server in the root of the WordPress site, via 'php -S localhost:3000'.
I added my db credentials in wp-config.php.
Then I added the following to the top of my wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:3000');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:3000');
```

I restarted the php server. I can run the basic navigation pages. However, when I to go localhost:3000/wp-admin and log in, my admin links are broken when I click them from the sidebar. The string 'admin' is missing from the urls. If I manually type the url into the browser I can access these resources.

How can I fix this? Does anyone know what I did wrong in setting up my local dev environment?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Can you add your errors msg here with it?

Answer (score 0):

Update: everything works fine if i log in via localhost:3000 > login page > login > click header dropdown.

However, I still have no idea why taking the route of localhost:3000/wp-admin breaks the links.

Comment: For those who bump across this post, "localhost:3000/wp-admin/index.php" should do the trick. For some reason, the PHP's built-in web server doesn't respect the url rewrite rules properly.